# res.render send data to EJS file and using it in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have this next GET function in express and in the `res.render()` function i'm sending to the EJS file the data i want to use, now my question is how can i use the data that i've sent to the EJS file in plain javascript in the same EJS file?
GET Funtion:

```js
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
 let pollId = req.params.id;
 Poll.findById(pollId, (err, poll) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  Vote.find(pollId, (err, votes) => {
   res.render('vote', {user: req.user, poll: poll, voteFail: req.flash('voteFail'),votes: votes });
  });
 });
});
```

And an example of how i want to use the data:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(<%votes%>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three main EJS Tags

```
<% %> and <%- %> and <%= %>

<% These will run script server side - There is no output - The user will not see this %> 

<%- These will inject javascript value into your html, unsanitized - you can pass html this way. %>

<%= These tags will inject the javascript value into your html, sanitized - html tags will appear as strings %>
```

If you want to console log in the browser console you can use...

```
<script>
   console.log( <%-votes%> );
</script>
```

If you want to console.log to the server side console simply use...

```
<% console.log(votes); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `<% %>` tags does not evaluate the expression. Use `<%= votes %>` instead.

Comment: It returns in the browser console this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @WackThat Not sure what you're trying to do in the end but in this particular scenario you could do `<% console.log(votes)%>` without the `<script>` tags and it should work.

Comment: I'm trying to use the data to make a Chart.js graph. you can do that only in plain js.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<%- votes -%>`, works for me.